# Graph SDK (.NET) SSO Support for Username & Password Flow

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using Microsoft Graph SDK in my .NET application (Windows Service) to retrieve Outlook calendar schedules through Graph API. Here, I am using username password flow for authentication (even though it is not recommended) and it is working properly.

Does anyone know whether the SSO flow is supported through this approach?

When I am doing some testing I was able to do an SSO sign-in flow is happening and I am able to retrieve calendar schedules. But what I don't know is how the redirection and all is happening without any user interaction? Is it all managed by SDK itself internally silently?

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft uses an Add-in architecture for SSO and Microsoft Graph. The best way for an Office Add-in to get authorized access to Microsoft Graph is to use the credentials from the user's Office sign on. This enables them to access their Microsoft Graph data without needing to sign in a second time.

Would suggest you to please go through the **Add-in architecture for SSO and Microsoft Graph section** of this below link. There is mention all the redirection of SSO flow with clear image and explanation.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph